# Can a power series of several variables be discontinuous on a compact set if it converges in every point of this set?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, power-series, counterexamples, several-complex-variables, continuity

Say we have a power series of two variables, with an associated function $f$ defined as
$$
\begin{split}
f(x, y) =\, & \sum_{n,m} a_{n,m}x^ny^m,\\
 & a_{n,m} \geq 0 \quad \forall n, m \in\mathbb{N},
\end{split}
$$ which is known to converge in each point of a compact set $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathbb{R_+}^2$. We can also assume $f$ to be bounded on $\mathcal{C}$.

Can $f$ have a point of discontinuity (or more) on $\mathcal{C}$?

Edit : As shown by [Tom Goodwillie with this nice counter-example](https://mathoverflow.net/a/426980/102634), it turns out to be possible for $f$ to be discontinuous. Thanks!

Edit : clarified question as per the inputs from Tom Goodwillie, David E Speyer and Daniele Tampieri.

Comment: Did you really mean to write $a_{n,m}\ge 0$?

Comment: If not, what you mean by convergence? There is the question of absolute versus relative convergence.

Comment: What is the role of compactness in the question? If there is a sequence of points $p_k$ with limit $p$, and if $f$ converges at each $p_k$ and at $p$, and if the limit of $f(p_k)$ is different from $f(p)$, then this is all happening in a compact set.

Comment: Thank you for your input, Tom. I indeed meant to add this non-negativity condition, and since $(x,y) \in\mathbb{R}_+^2$, absolute convergence is assumed to happen in every point.

Comment: Compactness may not be very important, but I meant to say that the set is "constraining" enough, hoping this would prevent some pathological cases.

Comment: I agree with your last comment, but I wonder if such a function $f$ could exist / if someone could provide such an example of a function. I couldn't come up with anything, but I'm not very literate in power series of several variables.

Comment: I don't understand, $(1-2xy) \sum (x^2+y^2)^n$ is not absolutely convergent at  $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$. Writing it as $\sum (x^2+y^2)^n - 2 xy \sum (x^2+y^2)^n$, the first sum only contains terms $x^{2a} y^{2b}$ and the second only contains terms $x^{2a+1} y^{2b+1}$, so there is no cancellation and the original  sum is absolutely convergent if and only if each of $\sum (x^2+y^2)^n$ and $2 xy \sum (x^2+y^2)^n$ are absolutely convergent. These latter sums clearly diverge at $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of a Reinhardt domain: these kind of domains are defined for power series in the complex euclidean space $\Bbb C^n$, and they are convergence sets for power series if and only if their image through a logarithmic map (see [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Reinhardt_domain) for all the relevant definitions) is convex in $\Bbb R^n$ but you are already working in the real space thus you perhaps are using a different definition.

Comment: You're right David, this example is actually quite bad (it's actually an extension of $f$ rather than a point of convergence of the series, which doesn't really make sense for the problem at hand). But then it leaves me wondering about the more general result, whether a series of two variables would be continuous in every point of absolute convergence! I will edit my post consequently.

Comment: I admit I phrased it in a confusing way Daniele, because I'm indeed interested in positive values of $(x,y)$. It is my understanding that absolute convergence in $\mathcal{C}$  means convergence on a domain $\Omega = \{z = (z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 | (|z_1|,|z_2|) \in \mathcal{C}\}$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$. I wanted to say that we can assume this set to be a complete log-convex Reinhardt domain, so that $\mathcal{C}$ is not necessarily part of the interior of the domain of convergence (which would give continuity). But this is actually not useful information, so I'll just remove it!

Comment: What do we know for one complex variable?  If a power series with radius of convergence $1$ actually converges everywhere on the unit circle, must it be continuous there?

Comment: It seems to me that it does by virtue of normal convergence. However I can't seem to generalize it to dimension 2: normal convergence can be used to get continuity in the interior of the domain of convergence (if $(x_0,y_0)$ is a boundary point then uniform convergence can be obtained on $\{(x,y)$ with $0 \leq x \leq x_0, 0 \leq y \leq y_0\}$ because $a_{n,m}x^ny^m \leq a_{n,m}x_0^ny_0^m$), but it doesn't seem to prove convergence on the boundary, e.g. if this boundary is defined by $|xy|=1$ then I can't find such a majoration since x decreases when y increases and vice versa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The series $f(x,y)=y+xy+x^2y+x^3y+\dots$ converges to $0$ when $y=0$, and converges to $y/(1-x)$ when $|x|<1$. This function is not continuous at $(x,y)=(1,0)$.

Comment: Thank you Tom, this is an interesting series! It definitely shows that continuity is not necessarily happening if there is absolute convergence on every point, so I'll edit the original post with a link to your counter-example for this more general condition. However, it still seems continuous to me on every compact set containing only points of absolute convergence, including $(1,0)$ (it looks like we need to stay sufficiently close to the line $x=1$ to get a divergent sequence, and this is what the compacity prevents from happening here).

Comment: The sum is absolutely convergent on the compact set $x \geq 0$, $y \geq 0$, $x+y \leq 1$, and is still discontinuous when restricted to this triangle.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I didn't realise it but indeed, the series' value is constantly 1 along the line $y =1-x$, so its limit in $(1,0)$ is $1 \neq 0 = f(1,0)$. My bad! I'll edit and mark this as solved then.