# What can be said about cluster sets for power series of two variables?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, power-series, counterexamples, several-complex-variables, continuity

I'm still trying to prove the continuity of a function $u$ which can be interpreted as the restriction of a power series of two variables, [which I haven't managed to approach the right way yet](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426942/can-a-power-series-of-several-variables-be-discontinuous-on-a-compact-set-if-it/426980). To give more context about this function and the associated power series:

- the power series coefficients are all non-negative;
- it converges (at least) on a domain $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_+^2 | x + y \leq 1\}$, and the original function $u$ is defined on the part of the boundary defined by $\{(x, 1-x) | x \in [0,1]\}$;
- there is some value $0 < x_0 < 1$ (so the tangent/normal is well-defined for the domain considered in $(x_0, 1-x_0)$) such that $u(x) = 1$ for all $0 \leq x < x_0$ and $u_{|[x_0, 1]}$ decreases continuously from some value $\alpha \leq 1$ to $0$ (so we are interested in showing left-continuity at $x_0$, or to put it another way $\alpha=1$).

Following [the counter-example I received in reply to my previous question linked above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426942/can-a-power-series-of-several-variables-be-discontinuous-on-a-compact-set-if-it/426980#426980), I got interested in looking at what level sets look like, and noticed on a couple of simple examples that they tend to "flow" regularly in $\mathbb{R}_+^2$ and only "converge" to a point of the first quadrant only if the series blows up in its neighborhood, and that all level sets tend to converge together (and not just part of them).

It drove me to the definition of cluster sets (the limit set of values of a function in every neighborhood of a point interesected with its domain of existence), which has some nice properties for power series of only one variable: indeed, the [Casorati-Sokhotskii-Weierstrass theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Casorati-Sokhotskii-Weierstrass_theorem#:%7E:text=Instead%20there%20is%20no%20direct%20generalization%20to%20the%20case%20of%20holomorphic%20functions%20of%20several%20complex%20variables) guarantees, in my understanding, that the cluster set is always either maximal or reduced to a single point. However, as highlighted in the Casorati-Sokhotskii-Weierstrass entry linked in the previous sentence, "there is no direct generalization to the case of holomorphic functions of several complex variables", but I couldn't find any discussion about it in the reference provided (B.V. Shabat).

So my question, motivated by this proof of continuity, is the following:
can we find some useful information about the cluster set at $x_0$ (in general if needed, i.e. even out of its domain of definition if it converges out of it), e.g typically if it is either a singleton or a maximal set, or are there counter-examples of power series of two variables with non-singleton cluster sets in which not all level sets converge when restricted to $\mathbb{R}_+^2$?